# RDS MySQL Storage Full ... When DB usage is low

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am getting Storage Full on one of my staging RDS tables and trying to figure out which DB/Tables is large ... but found that they are actually very small:

```
SELECT 
     table_schema as `Database`, 
     table_name AS `Table`, 
     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

[image]

```
SELECT table_schema "DB Name", 
Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM   information_schema.tables 
GROUP  BY table_schema;
```

[image]

Largest DB is only 16.7 MB so whats filling up my 10GB RDS?

[image]

From the pattern I am suspecting some cron ... which indeed there is a cron inserting data ... but as you can see from the table/db sizes its not that large ... what else can be filling up my RDS? Does backup/logs etc count as storage?

**UPDATE**:

I notice that on 26 July there is is spike in DB free storage and I tried looking into General Query log to determine what happened. I notice theres

```
 PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin-changelog.097019'
```

Wonder if it fails to purge logs subsequently?

Comment: What is the current setting for `expire_logs_days`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

to see how many, and of what size, your logs.  Then we can discuss purging some of them.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%'
```

Chase down the files that are mentioned; show us the output so we can discuss sizes.

The "general log" can grow very fast; turn it off when not using it.  And get rid of its log(s).

The "slow log" is very good for debugging performance problems.  Use `pt-query-digest` to summarize it, then toss it.

The "error log" should not be big.  If it is, then you probably have worse problems.

What is the current setting for `expire_logs_days`?